# CSV file into two arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, split

A bit stumped here. Attempting to Parse the numbers from a CSV file into two int variable arrays. However, it parses the first number only into both and not the second one.

`Example of CSV file:`

`10000,46`

`10001,76`

`10002,100`

```
string[] studentID = new string[STUDENT_TOTAL];
string[] studentMarks = new string[STUDENT_TOTAL];
studentID = line.Trim().Split(',');
studentMarks = line.Trim().Split(',');
int id = int.Parse(studentID[counter]);
int mark = int.Parse(studentMarks[counter]);
```

id should be 10000 and mark should be 46 for the first line. Any hints or full fixes. We are using Arrays only. No lists.

Comment: Just a quick note, what you're doing is not quite OOP - ideally you should have a "Student" class with an "Id" property and a "Marks" property. That way you don't have to maintain 2 arrays. Or you could at least do with a dictionary approach suggested in the answer. Also, I'm not sure where the requirement "Arrays only. No lists." comes from, but a list is nothing more than a fancy wrapper for an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line.Trim().Split(',') returns a string array. So split the line first, then assign each index to the relevent variables.

```
var lineValues = line.Trim().Split(',');
studentID = lineValues[0];
studentMarks = lineValues[1];
```

You will need to do this for each line. Is there a reason you're not using lists? That will make it easier since you can just add each value for each iteration of the file.

Comment: This is a weekly task that we do here for IT here in uni. Next week's tasks involve lists but for now, we use only Arrays. They are being written by line in a while loop until the endofstream in the .csv file, so a list isn't fully necessary for this task to be completed. I asked a person in class of a higher level and he gave the same answer as you did, works perfect now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you are only parsing the first value.

Your code effectively calls this:

```
int id = int.Parse(line.Trim().Split(',')[counter]);
int mark = int.Parse(line.Trim().Split(',')[counter]);
```

I assume that `counter` is always `0`.

You could make it work like this:

```
int id = int.Parse(line.Trim().Split(',')[0]);
int mark = int.Parse(line.Trim().Split(',')[1]);
```

But I suggest you do a bit of refactoring and do it this way:

```
var results =
    File
        .ReadAllLines(@"path")
        .Select(x => x.Trim().Split(','))
        .Select(x => new { id = x[0], mark = x[1] })
        .ToArray();

string[] studentID = results.Select(x => x.id).ToArray();
string[] studentMarks = results.Select(x => x.mark).ToArray();
```

Or even better, make a dictionary that will let you look-up the students marks:

```
Dictionary<int, int> lookup  =
    File
        .ReadAllLines(@"path")
        .Select(x => x.Trim().Split(','))
        .Select(x => new { id = x[0], mark = x[1] })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.id, x => x.mark);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Steve's answer, you could try splitting the entire file into a line array. For example:

```
string[] Lines = CSVText.Split( Enviroment.Newline );
```

Then using a for loop to read each line/column value
Or a **foreach** block.

```
for ( int line = 0; line < Lines.Length; line++ ) {
   string[] linedata = line.Trim().Split(',');
   studentID = linedata[0];
   studentMarks = linedata[1]; }
```

And he is right, lists are quite good for that.